# German adjectives that end in an "e" such as "leise" and "lose"

Tags: adjective, adjective-ending

**QUESTION**

1. Is there any interesting story, etymological or otherwise, behind German adjectives that end in an *e* the way *lose* and *leise* do?  (Why can't they be just *los* and *leis*?)
2. Are there other adjectives ending in an *e*?

**BACKGROUND**

According to [this Wiktionary page](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/lose#German), *lose* is a separate word from *los* and its predicative form is *lose*.  That is to say, one writes:

> Es ist lose.

Compare:

> Es ist groß.

But when modifying a substantive, *lose* behaves just as *los* might have.  For example, *ein loses Stück*.  Looking at this you might think it is made of *los* + *es* just as *großes* (in *ein großes Stück*) is made of *groß* and *es*.

The only other adjective I know which ends in *e* in the same sense is *leise*:

> Seid bitte leise!

In general German adjectives don't seem to like ending in a vowel.  I could only think of three that do:

> frei, neu, treu.

Comment: Some more examples: "böse", "fade", "feige", "gerade", "marode", "müde", "mürbe", "öde", "prüde", "rüde", "träge", "weise". Note that for many of these the final "e" is optional, and that there may be regional preferences for the form with or without "e".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are even much more adjectives ending in -e:

> behände, etepetete, flügge, frigide, gelinde, gerade, greise, irre, kirre, klasse, knülle, krude, leise, lose, marode, meschugge, morbide, müde, mürbe, perfide, pleite, präzise, prüde, rege, rigide, rüde, schade, scheiße, schnöde, schnuppe, solide, vage, valide, weise

And of course there are some foreign adjectives, but they don't count in this case:

> al dente, aubergine, benigne, liquide, live, beige, maligne, offline, offshore, online, papabile, up to date

But more interesting is this list:

> alleine, bange, blöde, böse, derbe, fade, feige, milde, nahe, öde, rapide, sachte, spröde, stupide, träge, trübe, zähe

They all end in -e, but all of them have a second form without this ending -e, and (less obvious) they all have one syllable less:

> allein, bang, blöd, bös, derb, fad, feig, mild, nah, öd, rapid, sacht, spröd, stupid, träg, trüb, zäh

Many German words end in a [Reduktionssilbe](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduktionssilbe). This is an unstressed syllable at the end of a word. The written form of such a syllable always contains the letter *e* as its vowel, and often there is no consonant after this e. In this case (a German word ending in an unstressed -e) this vowel is always pronounced as a [mid central vowel [ə]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mid_central_vowel).

But in colloquial speech (which varies regionally) and in local dialects this vowel often is omitted:

> Schule → Schul
>   Stunde → Stund
>   Leute → Leut
>   Auge → Aug
>   Aufgabe → Aufgab
>   ...

You can find evidence of such omitted *e*'s in many poems and lyrics, and it is usual to mark this omitted *e* with an apostrophe: *»Schul’, Stund’, Leut’, ...«*

Also many nouns used to end in -e in dative case:

> old: dem Raume, dem Manne, dem Worte, ...
>   new: dem Raum, dem Mann, dem Wort, ...

When you compare German from 19<sup>th</sup> century with modern German, you will find, that many of those ending *e*'s got lost, and this process is still going on, and it is transforming adjectives too. The adjectives with two forms are examples for this process, and the adjectives where only the form with -e exists, are just the ones that survived this process.