# Warum wurde "blöde" von "blöd" abgelöst?

Tags: history

Bis in die 1970er Jahren wird *blöde* (mit "e") häufiger verwendet als *blöd* (ohne "e"), dann kehrt sich das Verhältnis um ([Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bl%C3%B6de%2Cbl%C3%B6d&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbl%C3%B6de%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbl%C3%B6d%3B%2Cc0)):

[image: Google Ngram für blöd,blöde]

Warum?

---

Die Frage zu [German adjectives that end in an "e" such as "leise" and "lose"](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/43697/german-adjectives-that-end-in-an-e-such-as-leise-and-lose) hat nichts mit dieser Frage zu tun. Hier geht es um Formen mit und ohne "e" *desselben* Worts, während es dort generell um Adjective auf "e" geht. Leis und los gibt es nicht, blöd aber schon. (Ja, es gibt leis', mit Apostroph, und es gibt ein anderes Wort los, das mit lose nichts zu tun hat, aber nicht als geläufige Alternative zu leise und lose, wie blöd eine Alternative zu blöde ist.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [German adjectives that end in an "e" such as "leise" and "lose"](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/43697/german-adjectives-that-end-in-an-e-such-as-leise-and-lose)

Comment: Da  die Statistik keine Unterscheidung zwischen Adverb und flektiertem Adjektiv macht, sehe ich nicht, dass *man lässt zunehmend das e am Schluss weg* die einzige oder auch nur die bedeutsamste Erklärung ist. Von einer *Ablösung* kann ja wohl schwerlich die Rede sein.

Comment: @guidot Das flektierte Adjektiv ist ja aber wohl nicht plötzlich seltener verwendet worden – oder wenn doch, dann wäre das ja eine interessante Beobachtung, die einer Erklärung bedarf. Wenn wir davon ausgehen, dass die verschiedenen Flexionsformen über die Zeit hinweg ähnlich häufig verwendet werden, dürfte "blöd" nicht in den letzten fünfzig Jahren auf einmal häufiger auftreten. Dein Hinweis erklärt die beobachtbare Veränderung also nicht.

Comment: @OpelBlitz: Das flektierte Adjektiv ist sehr wohl nicht seltener verwendet worden (wenn auch nicht plötzlich, sondern allmählich). Und du hast Recht: Das ist eine interessante Beobachtung, die einer Erklärung bedarf. Genau diese Erklärung findest du in der Antwort auf die von mir verlinkte Frage.

Comment: Vorsicht mit den Ngrammen, bei Deinem ist z.B. die *blöde Sache* auch mitgezählt. Aber die Tendenz stimmt, wie man an diesem etwas besseren Ngram sehen kann: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ist+bl%C3%B6d%2Cist+bl%C3%B6de%2Csch%C3%B6n+bl%C3%B6d%2Csch%C3%B6n+bl%C3%B6de&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=20&smoothing=3

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: es ist schon deshalb [kein Duplikat, weil die andere Frage auf Englisch, diese hier auf Deutsch ist.](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/807/what-to-do-with-duplicate-questions-in-another-language). Alle anderen [Robo-Reviewer](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1326/community-moderation-robo-reviews-dont-help-anybody) bitte ich um mehr Sorgfalt.

Answer (score 1):

Schaut man sich folgendes Beispiel

> Das ist echt blöd.
>
> Das is echt blöde.

an, stellt man fest, dass beide Varianten momentan oft gebraucht werden (Internet-Suchmaschine: 47900 Treffer gegen 15600). Gefühlt klingt die Variante mit "blöde" für mich aber umgangssprachlicher, altmodischer und mehr nach Dialekt (siehe auch sächsisch: Orschwerbleede).

Das Warum der Entwicklung von Verwendungshäufigkeiten zu hinterfragen ist bei Sprache oft schwer, da es i.d.R. keine logische Erklärung gibt, warum bestimmte Wörter, Phrasen, Formen oder Varianten unmodern werden. Zum Beispiel ist "töricht" völlig aus der Mode gekommen.

Die wohl logischste Erklärung für mich wäre bei *blöd/blöde*, dass die Form mit der Endung -e wahrscheinlich zu sehr nach Dialekt klingt. Krasser verhält es sich mit "schön/schöne" - es klingt nicht besonders kultiviert, wenn der Sachse sagt: "Das is ja scheene."; dagegen lässt man "Das ist ja scheen." schon eher gelten.

Eine gewisse Rolle spielt wahrscheinlich auch, dass die e-Endung bei einigen Wörtern nach alter Sprache klingt, wie z.B. bei "Warte nur! **Balde** ruhest du auch." (Goethe).

Comment: Ngramme sind schon blöd, siehe mein anderes Beispiel, das ich im Kommentar zur Frage verlinkt habe.

Comment: @Takkat: Die attributive Verwendung hatte ich auch erst gegengecheckt. Man muss nur ein NGram bauen mit "blöder,blöde,blödes" (m/w/s). Daran sieht man, dass die allgemeine Verwendung von "blöd" zwar zugenommen hat, aber dass nach Bereinigung dieses Grundrauschens das angesprochene Problem aus der Frage grundsätzlich bleibt.