# Warum verliert "Schule" in Zusammensetzungen ("Schulhaus") das "e"?

Tags: compound

Wird ein zusammengesetztes schulbezogenes Wort gebildet, so scheint der vordere Teil stets "Schul-"/"schul-" zu sein, nie "Schul**e**-"/"schul**e**-" oder "Schul**en**-"/"schul**en**-":

If you form a school-related compound word, the first part seems to always be "Schul-"/"schul-", never "Schul**e**-"/"schul**e**-" or "Schul**en**-"/"schul**en**-":

- **schul**bezogen
- **Schul**haus
- **Schul**beginn
- Land**schul**heim
- **Schul**bus
- **Schul**medizin
- Hoch**schul**statut

Bei "Kirche" scheint es meist so zu sein, aber nicht immer:

With "Kirche" it seems to usually be that way, though not always:

- **Kirch**weih
- **Kirch**gang

aber/but:

- Kirch**en**oberhaupt

(Und letzteres scheint kein Plural zu sein, denn so jemand ist gewöhnlich Oberhaupt nur *einer* Kirche, nicht mehrerer.)

(And that last one doesn't seem to be plural, as such a person would be the head of only *one* church, not of several.)

Bei "Flasche" scheint die Zusammensetzung hingegen immer mit "Flasch**en**-"/"flasch**en**-" zu funktionieren:

In contrast, "Flasche" seems to always lead to compounds with "Flasch**en**-"/"flasch**en**-":

- Flasch**en**pfand
- Flasch**en**sammlung
- Flasch**en**öffner

(Wobei es bei den letzten beiden ein Plural sein könnte, da ja mehrere Flaschen gesammelt werden und sich mit dem Werkzeug mehrere öffnen lassen können sollten.)

Woran liegt das? Gibt es eine Regel, wann bei Zusammensetzungen ein unbetontes *e* (oder gar jede [Reduktionssilbe](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/43700/22560)?) weggelassen wird und wann es belassen oder gar um ein *n* oder andere Laute / Buchstaben ergänzt wird?

---

(Well, the latter two might be plural, as it'd be a collection of several bottles and as the tool should be usable for opening several bottles.)

Why is that? Is there some rule when a final unstressed *e* (or even any final [Reduktionssilbe](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/43700/22560)?) will be dropped in compounds, and when it would be kept or even augmented with an *n* or another sound/letter?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Wenn zusammengesetzte Substantive gebildet werden, wird zwischen die einzelnen Bestandteile ein Fugenlaut eingefügt. Der häufigste Fugenlaut ist die sogenannte Nullfuge. Damit ist gemeint, dass die beiden Bestandteile einfach unverändert zusammengefügt werden:

- Nullfuge

  > Gasthaus, Haustür, Türblatt, Blattschuss, Schussapparat, ...

Der zweithäufigste Fugenlaut ist ein *s*, dem manchmal noch ein *e* vorangestellt wird (*es*):

- -s-, -es-

  > Schweinsbraten, Ansichtskarte, Religionsfreiheit, ...

Ähnlich häufig:

- -n-, -en-

  > Schwanengesang, Heldentat, Sternenhimmel

Deutlich seltener:

- -e-

  > Mauseloch, Hundeleine, ...
- -er-

  > Kindergeld, Hühnerei, ...
- -ens-

  > Schmerzensgeld

Und dann gibt es noch die Sonderform der Subtraktionsfuge, bei der nichts hinzugefügt wird, sonder sogar noch etwas weggenommen wird. Anstelle des ganzen Wortes besteht das vordere Wort nur noch aus seinem Stamm:

- Subtraktionsfuge

  > Kronprinz, Seelsorger, Schulbus, ...

---

### Regeln

... gibt es so gut wie keine. Anders gesagt: Wenn man versucht Regeln zu formulieren, wird man bald feststellen, dass man am Ende mit deutlich mehr Ausnahmen und Ausnahmen von Ausnahmen dasteht als man Regeln gefunden hat.

Einige Fugenlaute leiten von einem Genitiv ab (*Kindesweglegung, Kindskopf*), andere von einem Plural (*Kindergarten*), aber z.B. im Fall der *Religionsfreiheit* rührt das *s* von gar keiner Form des ersten Wortes her.

Es gibt auch Wortpaare, die man mit unterschiedlichen Fugenlauten zusammenfügen kann, wobei man Wörter mit unterschiedlichen Bedeutungen erhält (*Gasthaus - Gästehaus*).

Auch dürfte bekannt sein, dass es regionale Unterschiede gibt (in Österreich: *Adventkalender, Schweinsbraten,* in weiten Teilen Deutschlands aber: *Adventskalender, Schweinebraten*)

Es existieren aber auch zusammengesetzte Wörter in mehreren Versionen, die im gesamten deutschen Sprachraum ohne Bedeutungsunterschied in Verwendung sind: *Erbschaft(s)steuer, Seminar(s)arbeit.*

Viele der vorangegangenen Beispiele haben auch gezeigt, dass die Fugenlaufe auch dann uneinheitlich sind, wenn das erste Wort dasselbe ist:

> Krone: Kronleuchter, Kronendach
> Birne: Birnbaun, Birnensaft
> Kind: Kindergarten, Kindesalter, Kindskopf, Kindfrau
> Welt: Weltkrieg, Weltenbummler

Comment: Sehr gut erklärt!

Comment: _Subtraktionsfuge_ wird mein neues Lieblingswort :D Im Übrigen gibt es sogar Variation zwischen _-s-_ und _-es-_: _Manneskraft_, _mannshoch_.

Comment: In *Arbeiterorganisation* ist -er- keine Fuge.  Arbeitsorganisation und Arbeiterorganisation ist kein Wortpaar, das man durch unterschiedliche Fugenlauten bekommt.

Comment: @Eller: Stimmt. Ich habe das korrigiert.